# Xamarin Forms View only renders when Added as a child in the codebehind

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.forms, prism

I have a custom View that I am trying to pass as `List<T>` to. For some reason when trying to load the page the app throws a `System.ArrayTypeMismatchException`.

Here is the class:

```
public class DiaryCalendarCustomView : View
{
    MiscFunctions misctools = new MiscFunctions();

    private List<DiaryNextContactEventModel> _eventList = new List<DiaryNextContactEventModel>();

    public List<DiaryNextContactEventModel> EventList
    {
        get { return _eventList; }
        set { _eventList = value; }
    }

    public void SetSelectedDate (DateTime selectedDate)
    {
        SelectedDate = selectedDate;

        Settings.Current.NextContactContactDate = selectedDate.ToLocalTime();
    }

    public DateTime SelectedDate { get; set; }

    public DiaryCalendarCustomView()
    {
    }
}
```

View Model:

```
private List<DiaryNextContactEventModel> _eventList = new List<DiaryNextContactEventModel>();

public List<DiaryNextContactEventModel> EventList
{
    get { return _eventList; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _eventList, value); }
}
```

When I add static data to the EventList object it works fine and when I remove the Binding from the XAML view it works as well. So the issue appears to be that xamarin is trying to convert my list into another type of enumerable and that's where it is failing.

XAML:

```
<Grid VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
       <Grid.Children>
            <partials:DiaryCalendarCustomView EventList="{Binding EventList}"/>
       </Grid.Children>
 </Grid>
```

Debugging and searching around hasn't really offered anything useful. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use custom property in XAML, you need to declare it in your view. Your code seems fine, just follow some tutorial like this: [Creating Custom Controls with Bindable Properties in Xamarin.Forms](https://mindofai.github.io/Creating-Custom-Controls-with-Bindable-Properties-in-Xamarin.Forms/) and add the missing pieces, so the property definiton and propertyChanged method:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty EventListProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
                                                         propertyName: "EventList",
                                                         returnType: typeof(List<DiaryNextContactEventModel>),
                                                         declaringType: typeof(DiaryCalendarCustomView),
                                                         defaultValue: "",
                                                         defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay,
                                                         propertyChanged: EventListPropertyChanged);
```

and also:

```
private static void EventListPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
{
    var view = (DiaryCalendarCustomView) bindable;
    view.EventList = (List<DiaryNextContactEventModel>) newValue;
}
```

Also make sure that your class implements INotifyPropertyChanged interface, so when you change EventList in EventListPropertyChanged, the view will get reloaded

Comment: Hi there, thank you for the answer I have added a BindableProperty as you mentioned above and I have read through that tutorial to see if I am missing something, but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: strange, does the method EventListPropertyChanged get called?

Comment: the page doesn't load, it crashes on `InitializeComponent()`

Comment: To correct my previous statement, after I moved the code from the code behind to the custom view class and messed around with it a bit (also had to fix some null issues) the page now loads. My only issue now is that I can't seem to update it with the binding data once my request comes back.

Comment: And to follow this one up as well. Figured out it was because the calendar wasn't redrawing. Changed some more code around and we are good to go. Thank you heaps for pointing me in the direction of this. Have a good one!

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out, have a great day also :)